# Forward incoming connection on one adapter to another adapter?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, iptables, port

I have two adapters on a server.

For the sake of this example, let's call them ad1 and ad2.

```
 ad1, ip = xxx.xxx.x.x (internet connection)
 ad2, ip = 192.168.1.1 (this system is the gameway for 192.168.1.5)
```

I need to forward connections coming in on `ad1` on port `1234` to an ip on ad2 that is `192.168.1.5` on port `1238`.

I need to know how to do this for both UDP and TCP, but in seperate commands as some times I'll need to forward UDP and some times I'll need to forward TCP.

I'm pretty new to using iptables, so just looking for some help.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks to [amauk](https://www.reddit.com/user/amauk) on reddit for this answer. Figured I'd post it here as well in case anyone came across this question.**

First, you need to enable IP forwarding.
This is disabled by default, for security reasons.

`vim /etc/sysctl.conf`
`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

Then run the following to commit the changes and reload the sysctl configuration

`sysctl -p`

Then you need to write the IPTables rules to forward the connections.

TCP

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ad1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5:1238
```

UDP

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ad1 -p udp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5:1238
```

Packets incoming from interface ad1 `-i ad1` matching the criteria (TCP/UDP + port number), NAT to destination:port

You'll also need to save the IPTables rules somehow, and have these restored on boot
Exactly how you do this is distro specific.

*edit*
For deleting rules, use `-D` (delete) in place of `-A` (append)

Eg.
To delete the TCP forwarding rule

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i ad1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.5:1238
```